# Hide row when a field is empty - Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, row

So I have an expenditures subform in Access that has two columns: YearNo and Expenditures. I'm trying to set it up that when a yearno field is empty, the row is not visible but the value in expenditures isn't deleted from the backend table.

The code I'm trying to use is

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    If Me.YearNo = “” or IsNull(Me.YearNo) Then
       Me.Amount.Visible = False
End Sub
```

However, the problem I'm encountering is that this makes the entire expenditures column hidden. I just want the row to not be visible. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wound up having to do was create a query attached to the table and set it to filter on load.

Answer (score 0):

If the subform is based on a query in your db, you can modify the WHERE clause to filter out 0-length or Null [YearNo]s.

Or, you should be able to set the Filter property of the subform in Design view.  If you look under Properties -> Data, there is the Filter property.  If you enter

```
"[YearNo] <> '' AND [YearNo] IS NOT NULL"
```

then set the Filter On Load property to True, that should give you what you want.  (Remove the code you already have on Form_Load as well.)